# Global struct array unconventional problem

Tags: c

I was making a project for my university and I encountered a big and strange problem.
I've created my struct and tried to make a global array out of it but the result was very strange. The array has 6 cells but when I try to print the struct's fields in the main, appears to have many more cells than 6.
These are the structs and the global array:

```
#include "config.h" //K, P and T are defined in this header 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct infocash{
 int fixed_time;
 int service_time;
 int cash_products;
 int full;
 QueuePtr customers;
 pthread_cond_t cashqueue;
}InfoCash;

typedef struct infoshop{
 int time;
 int customer_products;
}InfoShop;

typedef struct queue{
 InfoShop cust_info;
 struct queue* next;
}Queue;
typedef Queue* QueuePtr;

InfoCash cashes[K];

InfoShop init_shop_info();
void init_cash_info(int i);

void custfun(){
  InfoShop infoshop = init_shop_info();
}

void cashfun(void* arg){
  int* i = arg;
  init_cash_info(*i);
}
```

and this is the main:

```
int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  pthread_t tid_cust[C];
  pthread_t tid_cash[K];
  for(int i = 0; i < C; i++) pthread_create(&tid_cust[i], NULL, (void*)custfun, NULL);
  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++) pthread_create(&tid_cash[i], NULL, (void*)cashfun, &i);
  for(int i = 0; i < C; i++) pthread_join(tid_cust[i], NULL);
  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++) pthread_join(tid_cash[i], NULL);
  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++) printf("%d\n", cashes[i].fixed_time);
}

InfoShop init_shop_info(){
  InfoShop info;
  unsigned int seed = rand();
  info.time = 10 + rand_r(&seed)%T-10+1;
  info.customer_products = rand_r(&seed)%P+1;
  return info;
}

void init_cash_info(int i){
  unsigned int seed = rand();
  cashes[i].fixed_time = 20 + rand_r(&seed)%80-20+1;
  cashes[i].service_time = 0;
  cashes[i].cash_products = 0;
  cashes[i].customers = NULL;
  cashes[i].full = 0;
  pthread_cond_init(&cashes[i].cashqueue, NULL);
  return;
}
```

That's what happens:

1. the first value is ALWAYS 0
2. if I increase K the array cashes doesn't trigger segmentation fault
3. this method gives me problems also when I use a simple int array[X]

What's going on? What am I not considering?
Thanks for ur help ^^

Comment: _"the first value is ALWAYS 0"_ well do you set it to something else? _"if I increase `K` the array cashes doesn't trigger segmentation fault"_ at which point do you increase it? At runtime or before compiling? Also how is `K` defined? Is it a global variable or a marko?

Comment: K is a macro defined as 6 in an header which I include in the "preprocessor directives".
What do you mean with "At runtime or before compiling", im just populating the struct array with a function used by a thread.. I can post the full code if you want

Comment: 1-> Value is zero because you do not set it
2->Memory is assigned to the array as per the size of K. So there will not be a segmentation fault
3-> The number of prints will be equal to the number of items in the array. Each array will have 6 variables

Comment: @hashdefine I do not set it? What do u mean? I've a function used by a thread which sets every field of these array cells.
The number of prints is not equal to the cell of the array (which should be K but it's not).
I didn't understand the part of segfault.. that memory is not allocated.. segfault should be triggered for definition

Comment: @babayaga98 you don't show this function, so how are we supposed to know it exists? Also, with incomplete code like that, how are we supposed to answer your questions? There's nothing wrong with the parts of the code you've shown: `cashes` has `K` elements, and the for-loop will execute `K` times, which is probably exactly what should happen

Comment: @FelixG well I'll post the full code then. I avoided to do that because maybe was an easier problem to find, sorry

Comment: It doesn't have to be the full code (or rather it shouldn't be), just a [mre]. That means the code has to be just complete enough to be compilable and show the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Well actually is really short code so I uploaded it, hope u can find what's so strange in these global arrays

Comment: `so I uploaded it,` - what are the values of `K` and `C`? `init_cash_info`? [repl compiler link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/StrikingWorldlyOffice) `unsigned int seed = rand();
  rand_r(&seed)` No. Just use `rand()` then.

Comment: That's not the same thing.. rand_r is a re-entrant function which is used for threads.
rand() is used only to generate a random seed, not a number

Comment: By the way K is 6, P is 200, T is 100 and C is 50. I reuploaded the prototype of functions, sorry I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in global declaration program crashes, In another case while initializing it inside function if k = 0 at first and the only upto index 4 you can store values if array type is int depending upon type of array and size of that type.

If you want to apply it really then do by creating singly linkedlist

Answer (score -1):

If you're not doing any initialization on your structs, in C the values are whatever happens to be memory.  It can appear to be 0 always for the first element, but it is not guaranteed.  It is up to the programmer to set the values.

For the "if I increase K the array cashes doesn't trigger segmentation fault" issue, segfaults do not necessarily occur if you read past the end of an array (and in practice often don't if you don't go too far).  There is no way to determine "if you have many more cells" in an array in C by itself.

Comment: `InfoCash cashes[K];` is at file scope, it's initialized to `0` and `NULL`.